# Send UPC digits from raspberry pi to POS

Tags: raspberry-pi, embedded, usb, pos, pyusb

We usually see a barcode scanner connected to a POS(usually a computer) but now I want RP seats in between scanner and POS and read upc number to do some other work but don't know how to send read UPC to POS from RP.
How can I do that?

Workflow: barcode scanner reads upc and send it to RP and I do have the code on RP that read upc digits but now want to send the extracted upc number to POS and stuck there

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you intend to physically insert a Raspberry Pi between the point-of-sale device and the barcode scanner to create a new workflow, but logically it just breaks the chain of communications.

It is not the era of legacy COM port communication that used the DSUB9 connector, but now it is connected by the USB protocol, so it is not possible to insert new functions by such means.

Rather than that, it is more realistic to modify the POS application to add new functions to the processing when barcode data is received.

If it's a method close to your idea, as mentioned above, change the barcode scanner to a model that physically connects with a DSUB9 connector, and set the application to use the corresponding COM port, Raspberry Pi Is it inserted in between like an RS232C line monitor?

Otherwise, the Raspberry Pi would have to behave like a barcode scanner at the USB protocol level, such as Vendor ID Product ID.

Comment: can't find DSUB9 connector, is it a connector? Can you link me to a scanner with this connector?

Comment: Many vendor scanners support the DSUB9 connector as one of the models. Some scanners can be switched by simply changing the interface cable. See, for example, page 102 of this manual. [DS4608 Imaging Scanner Product Reference Guide](https://www.zebra.com/content/dam/zebra_new_ia/en-us/manuals/barcode-scanners/ds4608-prg-en.pdf)